# How to get an UPDATED size of a folder using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to check the size of a specific folder using Powershell. The size of this folder is constantly growing. However, despite this, Powershell always returns the same size.

**Example:**
Powershell returns 1000079693
wait 5 seconds
Powershell STILL returns 1000079693

The only exceptions to this is if I go to the folder, right click and click properties. I believe this updates something in the OS. Or I can wait a long time (like 5 minutes) After doing this, Powershell will show me a new number for the folder size.

My question is, how can I FORCE Powershell to get the most updated folder size right away, instead of returning the old size?

```
try{
    $size = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GUIClicker\ButtonsThatAreReady" -Recurse -ErrorAction stop |
        Measure-Object -property length -sum
    Write-Host $size.sum
} catch{
    Write-Host ":Error:"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce this problem?  I just tried your code on a folder on my laptop and it worked as expected.  I added a single character to an existing text file in the folder and it picked up the change straight away.

Comment: So I just tried, and the same is the case for me (adding a character or new file to the folder will increase the size immediately.) However, my folder is being updated by a script, and not manually. So I think there's something special when files are updated via a script instead of by hand. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce that script here.

Comment: Unless your script does something special (in which case you'd need to show us what it does) there is no difference between updating a file manually or via script.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this while your script is running (from a separate PowerShell session)

```
DO {
$a
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\GUIClicker\ButtonsThatAreReady" -Force | Measure-Object -Property length -Sum | Select-Object Sum
Start-Sleep -s 1
$a++
} Until ($a -ge 10)
```

As written this will run for ~10 seconds, substitute the 10 with however many seconds you want to execute for and/or change the sleep from 1 second to however many you need.